# Python 2.7 regular expressions finding specific html code

Tags: html, regex, parsing, python-2.7, web-scraping

So, I've been given another task from my professor, and this one is bugging me.

> Write a program that can replicate this sort of exchange:

```
`What is the url to the course page? http://registrar.indiana.edu/browser/soc4148/index.shtml
Searching for departments on: http://registrar.indiana.edu/browser/soc4148/index.shtml
Departments loaded. List them (Y/N)? y
AAAD    AAAD/index.shtml
AADM    AADM/index.shtml
AAST    AAST/index.shtml
ABEH    ABEH/index.shtml
AERO    AERO/index.shtml
AFRI    AFRI/index.shtml
AMID    AMID/index.shtml
AMST    AMST/index.shtml
ANAT    ANAT/index.shtml
ANTH    ANTH/index.shtml
ASCS    ASCS/index.shtml
AST     AST/index.shtml
BIOC    BIOC/index.shtml
BIOL    BIOL/index.shtml
BIOT    BIOT/index.shtml
[too many to list at once]
TEL     TEL/index.shtml
THTR    THTR/index.shtml
TOPT    TOPT/index.shtml
VSCI    VSCI/index.shtml

What department would you like? aero
Looking for courses on: http://registrar.indiana.edu/browser/soc4148/AERO/index.shtml

AERO-A101.shtml     AERO-A 101     INTRO TO THE AIR FORCE TODAY
AERO-A301.shtml     AERO-A 301     AIR FORCE LEADERSHIP STUDIES


What is the url to the course page? http://registrar.indiana.edu/browser/soc4148/index.shtml
Searching for departments on: http://registrar.indiana.edu/browser/soc4148/index.shtml
Departments loaded. List them (Y/N)?n
What department would you like? INFO
Looking for courses on: http://registrar.indiana.edu/browser/soc4148/INFO/index.shtml
...
...
...`
```

And the code repeats. We are only allowed to use list comprehension and regular expressions, as well as the urllib and os libraries.

If you look at the source code of the webpages, you find that the links are listed as such:

> First page (list of departments)

```
'<strong><a href="AAAD/index.shtml">AAAD</a></strong> African Am & Afri Diaspora Std<br />
<strong><a href="AADM/index.shtml">AADM</a></strong> Arts Administration<br />
<strong><a href="AAST/index.shtml">AAST</a></strong> Asian American Studies<br />
<strong><a href="ABEH/index.shtml">ABEH</a></strong> Animal Behavior<br />
<strong><a href="AERO/index.shtml">AERO</a></strong> Aerospace Studies<br />
<strong><a href="AFRI/index.shtml">AFRI</a></strong> African Studies<br />
<strong><a href="AMID/index.shtml">AMID</a></strong> Apparel Merch/Int Design<br />
<strong><a href="AMST/index.shtml">AMST</a></strong> American Studies<br />
<strong><a href="ANAT/index.shtml">ANAT</a></strong> Anatomy<br />'
```

And, very similarly:

> Second page (list of courses)

```
'<td>
<strong><a href="AERO-A101.shtml">AERO-A 101</a></strong> INTRO TO THE AIR FORCE TODAY<br>
<strong><a href="AERO-A201.shtml">AERO-A 201</a></strong> EVOLUTION USAF AIR & SPACE PWR<br>
<strong><a href="AERO-A301.shtml">AERO-A 301</a></strong> AIR FORCE LEADERSHIP STUDIES<br>
</td>
<td>
<strong><a href="AERO-A401.shtml">AERO-A 401</a></strong> NATL SEC AFFRS/PREP ACTV DUTY<br>
</td>'
```

To spare the functions I have to open the webpages and get the contents (using .read() in order to take the code as one large string). I was able to get the links to the departments (the first part of the code) using these regular expressions and loops.

```
'print "Searching for departments on: " + url
links = [item for item in re.findall('<strong><a href="[\w./-]+">', contents)]

names = [item for item in re.findall('.shtml">[\w]+[-]?[\w]?[-]?[ ]?[\d]?[\d]?[\d]?</a></strong>', contents)]

descripts = [item for item in re.findall('</a></strong>[\s][\w\s]+[&/-]?[\w\s]+<br', contents)]

for link in links:
    link = link.replace('<strong><a href="', '')
    link = link.replace('">', '')
    the_links.append(link)

for name in names:
    name = name.replace('.shtml">', '')
    name = name.replace('</a></strong>', '')
    the_names.append(name)

for each in descripts:
    each = each.replace('</a></strong> ', '')
    each = each.replace('<br', '')
    the_descripts.append(each)

while True:
    list_deps = raw_input("List them (Y/N)? ")
    if list_deps.lower() == "y":
        for i in range(len(links)):
            if len(the_links[i]) < 16:
                print the_names[i] + "\t" + the_links[i] + "\t\t" + the_descripts[i]
            else:
                print the_names[i] + "\t" + the_links[i] + "\t" + the_descripts[i]
        break
    elif list_deps.lower() == "n":
        break
    else:
        print "You must enter Y or N."'
```

But, my issue occurs when I attempt to use those same regular expressions for the second part (getting the course link, course name, and course description)

Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong? If the entirety of my code is needed, I can post or send it to those who wish to have it. I'm just not sure why my regular expressions work for getting the departments but not the courses.

> EDIT: Turns out I was using the user's input .lower() to go to the corresponding department page, but the user input needed to be .upper() or it went to a 404 page.

Comment: Even when I use '<strong><a href=".*">', replacing all of the regexes with .* instead of more specific and complication regex, getting the course info still does not work.

Comment: You offer to provide more code, but that won't really help. Can you isolate the problem to a *small* program with a simple input and output that shows the problem? It's unclear to us what actually goes wrong because you haven't described the problem any further than "my issue occurs".

Comment: Okay, I'll do my best.
Say I have a string:
'string = <td>
<strong><a href="AERO-A101.shtml">AERO-A 101</a></strong> INTRO TO THE AIR FORCE TODAY<br><strong><a href="AERO-A201.shtml">AERO-A 201</a></strong> EVOLUTION USAF AIR & SPACE PWR<br>
<strong><a href="AERO-A301.shtml">AERO-A 301</a></strong> AIR FORCE LEADERSHIP STUDIES<br>
</td>
<td>
<strong><a href="AERO-A401.shtml">AERO-A 401</a></strong> NATL SEC AFFRS/PREP ACTV DUTY<br>
</td>'

And I use the regexes I used above. Why won't the regexes find "AERO-A101.shtml", "AERO-A 101", and "INTRO TO THE AIR FORCE TODAY", and the other similars?